# Virtual Directory on Azure

Tags: php, azure

I’m trying to mount a PHP service on windows azure. I want to create a virtual directory and I need to keep the original parent folder structure. However, Azure takes the vitual directory as root folder. This configuration works withou any problem in IIS 7 and windows azure SDK.

For example. When accessing the address www.myService.cloudapp.net the ‘MyFolder/lib/admin’ must be accessed, but it must keep all parent folders structure and files, which will be used by PHP

I tried to do this using the ServiceDefinition.csdef file:

Case1

```
<Sites>
<Site name="Web" physicalDirectory="./MyFolder/lib/admin/">        
    <Bindings>
        <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="HttpEndpoint" />
    </Bindings>
</Site>
</Sites>
```

Case2

```
<Sites>
<Site name="Web" physicalDirectory="./MyFolder/lib/admin/">
    <VirtualDirectory name="admin" physicalDirectory="MyFolder/lib/admin"/>        
    <Bindings>
        <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="HttpEndpoint" />
    </Bindings>
</Site> 
</Sites>
```

Case3

```
<Sites>
<Site name="Web" physicalDirectory="./MyFolder/lib/admin/">
    <VirtualApplication name="admin" physicalDirectory="MyFolder/lib/admin">        
    <Bindings>
        <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="HttpEndpoint" />
    </Bindings>
</Site> 
</Sites>
```

In these cases azure makes the structure ‘E:\siterrot\0\admin’ and the parent folder of ‘admin’ is ‘0’ not ‘lib’ and PHP need acces to lib content.

Does azure support virtual directories?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to by doing something like:

```
<WebRole name="SampleWebApp">
  <Sites>
    <Site name="SampleSite" physicalDirectory="..\SampleWebApp">
      ...
       <VirtualDirectory name="Scripts"
                          physicalDirectory="..\SampleWebApp\Scripts" />
        <VirtualDirectory name="Styles"
                          physicalDirectory="..\SampleWebApp\Styles" />
      </VirtualApplication>
      ...
    </Site>
  </Sites>
  ...
</WebRole>
```

This is from:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg432956.aspx

Comment: It seems this configuration works in Azure 1.3, but not in current SDK version 1.6 (the last one)

Apart from this, it not works in the same way as IIS, because web root is the phisical directory, but also web file system so we can't access another directory in lib, if the physical directory is ./MyFolder/lib/admin/

Web "mounting" folder being the same as physical mouting server is expected behaviour or is a bug?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is going into your azure portal for your website and go to configure your application. Scroll all the way down to find "**Virtual applications and directories**" for this specific purposes.

[image: **enter image description here**]